# Blank lines when printing a .csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm using a basic block to sort and print a .csv file. It is sorted and printed correctly apart from several blank lines being printed but they don't exist within the actual csv file.

```
file = open("class1.csv", "r")
sort = sorted(file,key=operator.itemgetter(0))
for eachline in sort:
    print (eachline)
```

Comment: `operator.itemgetter(0)` will sort by the first _character_ of each line. Are you sure you weren't trying to sort by the first column of the CSV?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that iterating over a file leaves the newline characters on the end:

```
>>> for i in open("a.py"):
...     print(repr(i))
... 
'import math\n'
'\n'
'\n'
<snipped>
```

Therefore, when you print the lines, the `print` function adds another `"\n"` to the end, and you get something similar to:

```
>>> print("import math\n")
import math

>>>
```

The easiest way to remedy this (I am assuming you are using Python 3, judging by the brackets with the `print`) is to use the `end` option for `print`:

```
for eachline in sort:
    print(eachline, end="")
```

This will stop `print` from adding an extra `"\n"` (it adds `""` instead, which does nothing), and so there are no extra newlines:

```
>>> print("import math\n", end="")
import math
>>>
```

If you are on python 2 or don't want to modify the `print`, you can strip the `"\n"` using `str.replace`:

```
for eachline in sort:
    print(eachline.replace("\n", ""))
```

Comment: Using 'replace' worked brilliantly, thank you @matsjoyce

Comment: @Harry Could you please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer then, so that other users know this problem has been solved? Thanks.

Comment: For Python 2, you can simply use `print eachline,` to suppress the newline the `print` statement normally adds. This is equivalent to a `print(eachline, end="")` function call in Python 3.